# How to use grouped_collection_select to show multiple selection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, formtastic

I'm using the following code to display a tree view selection box of categories:

```
grouped_collection_select(:categories, :category_id, Category.top_level, :children, :name, :id, :name, :include_blank => true)
```

**How can I change it to allow multiple selection?**

Also, is it possible to have it display checkboxes instead of a select box?

Answer (score 5):

try

```
grouped_collection_select(:categories, :category_id, Category.top_level, :children, :name, :id, :name, {:include_blank => true}, { :multiple => true }
```

Comment: This is the correct solution.  The method ends with 2 independent hashes.  The first is for "options" the second is for "html options". The curly braces (on the first hash at least) are required to disambiguate which hash the values are being set on.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with

```
grouped_collection_select(:categories, :category_id, Category.top_level, :children, :name, :id, :name, :include_blank => true, { :multiple => true }
```

not tested!